# Calculation surface area for every cells

Tags: area, function, summarizing, surface, cell-size

Surface area= Plan area /cosine (in Radian) slope.
I used cell plan area by multiplying cell size for example 12,5*12,5=156,25square meters
Surface Area = 156,25/cosine slope
result became surface area for every cell but I don't know how I should get Sum of all cells in QGIS. Sum of all cell value would be Surface area.

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27777/how-to-sum-up-pixel-values-in-qgis